# Casting Any to Integer returns a NullPointerException from the API

Tags: android, casting, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit2

While getting data from the API, a NullPointerException was thrown because of casting Any to an integer.
If someone can tell.

```
val albums by remember {                                              
         mutableIntStateOf((artistStatsItem!!.albums!!.total!! as? Int)!!) 
}
```

```
data class Album(
    @field:SerializedName("created")
    val created: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("total")
    val total: Any? = null,         // <---

    @field:SerializedName("coming")
    val coming: Int? = null
)
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `Any` instead of for example `Int`? Also, the crash is occuring because `total` is probably null, and then `total!!` will throw an Exception,

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The answer of Yağmur Dikiciler worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val albums by remember {
mutableIntStateOf((artistStatsItem?.albums?.total as? Int) ?: 0)}
```

I think the error can be fixed this way. I hope that will be useful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).